# Ошибка при установки библиотеки zip в python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Проблем с установкой других библиотек на Python 3.10 нет. Ставил через команду pip install zip. Часть библиотеки скачалась и установилась, но затем установку прервала такая ошибка, будто она в самом коде:

```
 Using cached wsgiref-0.1.2.zip (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Halo Manash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bxo13ywq\wsgiref_a5a1385ae6074cacb670e77b85d55540\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
          import ez_setup
        File "C:\Users\Halo Manash\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bxo13ywq\wsgiref_a5a1385ae6074cacb670e77b85d55540\ez_setup\__init__.py", line 170
          print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке (SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' - отсутствуют скобки при вызове print), данная библиотека написана для Python 2. Если вам нужна работа с zip файлами, используйте стандартный модуль zipfile.

Comment: insolor скорей всего. Благодарю за разъяснение кода в ошибке.